# Binary data not stored properly in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, blob

I want to store a base64_encoded string as binary data. So use base64_decode() on the string before inserting in a LONGBLOB field of MySQL. So far so good, however when I retrieve the data from MySQL, I can't generate the correct base64_encoded string which I have started with...

How is this possible? Thanks in advance

***EDIT***

The stored data is an encrypted string with AES-256CBC OPENSSL encryption routine.

***CODE***

For my code I use OpenSSL to encrypt a string

```
$string = "Test";
$IV = "1234567890123456";
$key = "12345678901234561234567890123456";
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($string, "AES-256-CBC", $key, false, $IV);

$encrypted string is stored in LONGBLOB field by 
$sql_insert_data = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `TBLName` (String) Values(?)");
$sql_insert_data->bind_param('s', $mysqli->real_escape_string($encrypted));

//Thereafter, it is retrieved by a select statement
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($row['String'], "AES-256-CBC", $key, true, $IV);
```

When I do base64_encode on the string and store that as a TEXT value in the DB, the above works. However, when I do not, the above does not work...

Thanks

Comment: If you want to store a  base64_encoded string as binary data, why not use `base64_encode()` instead of `base64_decode()` on the string before inserting in a LONGBLOB field of MySQL? To get it back, you then use `base64_decode(columnname)` on that string to retrieve your original string. So `base64_decode(base64_encode('string'))` is `'string'`, but not the other way round, unless `'string'` is a proper base64-encoded string.

Comment: Because storing base64_encoded strings cost much more diskspace. I want to optimize my storage, but when I do I can't get the string back in it's original way. So I insert a base64_encoded string as LONGBLOB with base64_decode. When I retrieve the value I use base64_encode, but than it isn't the same as the begin string was

Comment: Ah, ok, I misunderstood that. Does `base64_decode(base64_encode('string'))` in your programming language return the original string? Can you add an example of a string that doesn't work? Also add the query you use to insert that string, maybe it changes (e.g. because of a `\0` or because of escapes). I guess a safer way would be to use the mysql function to de- and encode the string, as it should be safe to parse the base64-encoded original string into the query.

Comment: What do you mean? I have a base64_encoded string which I insert with prepared statement in a LONGBLOB field base64_decoded() execute before. When I retrieve it and do base64_encode() I can't get the string back to original form

Comment: I mean: try `base64_encode(base64_decode(string))` in your programming language (without involving mysql/the query), there might already be a problem there (e.g.: your original string is actually not correctly base64 encoded). The second thing is that the prepared statement might manipulate the string (escape some values). So my idea was: pass your original encoded string to a query, dont decode it yourself; so the query itself decodes the string, e.g. `insert into table (blobcolumn) select from_base64(?)`, and parse your string there and let mysql do the decoding.

Comment: Man, I don't understand what you mean, could you set up a pseudocode?

Comment: This was already pseudocode (and as close to actual code as possible without knowing your tablenames). Maybe you should post your query and especially name your programming language.

Comment: Please provide a chain of routines where you programatically describe your current setup.

Comment: Functions are called TO_BASE64() and FROM_BASE64() ([reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html)), what makes me think you are using some other language (possibly PHP) and doing something wrong there. And having "does not work" as sole problem description does not help.

Comment: My language indeed is PHP, I will update my post with some code

Comment: Do _not_ treat BLOBs as "strings".

Answer (score 1):

You are using prepared statements incorrectly:

```
$sql_insert_data->bind_param('s', $mysqli->real_escape_string($encrypted));
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ :-!
```

Your code will add random backslashes to the binary stream. You don't need `real_escape_string()` at all.

Comment: Well, when I don't use prepared statement the BLOB field is as large as when I just use base64_encode and save it as a TEXT field... so why should I than?

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Prepared statements are basically syntactic sugar to separate code from data, they do not alter neither your data nor your structure.

Comment: Well, I have plenty of base64_encoded strings which I have to save in my DB. So, my DB get's quite large so I would like to optimize. However, when I save the base64_encoded string as LONGBLOB and not base64_encoded, I can't get it to a good base64_encoded string when selecting it from the DB. got what i mean? :p

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren I have a feeling that you should make your mind first. It's impossible to tell what is your problem from your entangled explanations.

Comment: Understood, I thought your comments were about my answer (the data corruption reported is definitively there and needs to get fixed).

Comment: So, what is your opinion in fixing it? I don't understand both answers in relation to my problem :p

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren As long as you cannot ask a question, there is hardly be an answer.

Comment: damn son, the question is how to I optimize the storage of base64_encoded data successfully in mysql. That's all

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren Your question is "I can't generate the correct base64_encoded string which I have started with" and that's what my answer tries to address. "how to optimize the storage of base64_encoded data successfully in mysql" appears to be a different question and that's fine, but the middle of another question is probably not the best place to ask it.

Comment: Phrased differently, `bind_param` and `real_escape_string` do similar things.  Do one or the other, but _not both_.

Answer (score -1):

"damn son, the question is how to I optimize the storage of base64_encoded data successfully in mysql. That's all."  -- See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42080296/1766831