# Base64 MySQL storage space optimalisation

Tags: mysql, optimization, base64, storage

I have plenty of base64_encoded strings which I save in my MySQL DB. However, since base64_encoded strings are 33% larger, I would like to know how I can optimize my DB storage (Now I store my strings in a LONGTEXT field, but what about LONGBLOB or something similar?). So, how I can save my data (which is now base64 encoded) more optimized so I save storage space... (When selecting the value, I still have to be able to encode it base64 safely again).

Thanks

Comment: According to your comments at [Binary data not stored properly in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064646/binary-data-not-stored-properly-in-mysql#comment71308438_42067769): *" the question is how to I optimize the storage of base64_encoded data ... in mysql"*. How is this question different than your previous question? And you should show your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binary data not stored properly in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064646/binary-data-not-stored-properly-in-mysql)

Comment: @jww - those links point out that you should not treat blobs as strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 5.6.1 or later, FROM/TO_BASE64() are available in MySQL.

Base64 is plain ascii text.  Storing base64 in a `TEXT` is no problem.  No escaping is necessary since (I think) there are no naughty characters.  But storing the result of FROM_BASE64 needs a `BLOB` (of some size).

So...

```
INSERT INTO t (myblob) VALUES ( FROM_BASE64('UmljayBKYW1lcw==') );

SELECT TO_BASE64(myblob) FROM t;
```

The `FROM_BASE64` will reconstruct the original (pre-base64) data.

Even better would be to compress instead:

```
INSERT INTO t (myblob) VALUES ( COMPRESS('UmljayBKYW1lcw==') );

SELECT UNCOMPRESS(myblob) FROM t;
```

That way, you will (probably) get more than the 33% _if the original (pre-base64) data was compressible.  If the original was a `.jpg` or some other already-compressed data, then you may as well use `FROM_BASE64` instead of `COMPRESS`.

Comment: So, using to_base64 combined with compress will save me the 33.3% overhead base64_encoded has? So I will use COMPRESS(TO_BASE64(STRING)) and to select UNCOMPRESS(FROM_BASE64(SELECTED STRING)) ?

Comment: It depends on what you are starting with.  It sounded like something is generating base64 strings, and you want to store them compactly in a table.  In that case, there is no need to repeat the conversion TO_BASE64 before compressing.  (Note:  I fixed my answer.)

Comment: Rick, thanks I will try this out. Besides, is it correct that you call FROM_BASE64 twice on your first example?

Comment: Thank Ricks, however when I use compress, the size isn't changing. How can this be possible? The string requires 200kb of storage and after compressing still 200kb of storage needed

Comment: You are saying that you take 200KB of base64 text, compress it, and `SELECT LENGTH(myblob)` comes out about 200K?  Was the raw data (_before_ converting to base64) an image or something else what is already compressed?  In that case, the raw data and the compressed result will be _about_ the same -- while the base64 will be about 25% bigger.

Comment: I experimented with some JPG thumbnails I have -- LENGTH(thumb) is about 2K; LENGTH(COMPRESS(TO_BASE64(thumb))) is also about 2K, usually within 1% of each other.

Comment: I modified my Answer to reflect some of this.  Was the original stuff an image?  A PDF?  What?

Comment: The original strings I tested with are encrypted strings from the OpenSSL library. using AES-(256|512) modes and base64_encoding the output with PHP. So perhaps, the output is compressed but than the compressed output is base64_encoded, which makes me expect to gain at least 25% on compressing it with MySQL since it compresses the base64_encoded (compressed OpenSSL output string).... Just my guessing. Thx for reply

Comment: The 25% comes from base64 -- Base 64 has 6 bits per 8 bit byte.  (Note: 64 = 2^6.)  The "wasted" 2 bits is 2/8 = 25%.  Phrased differently:  If you have 300 8-bit bytes, that's 2400 bits.  Divide that by 6, you get 400 bytes being needed for the base64 encoding.  (Note:  This paragraph does not mention "compression".)